# Displaying a Hashtable in a selectedOneMenu list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hashtable, selectonemenu

i have a Hashtable i want to display it in a selecteOneMenu any idea how to do it ?

```
itemCat = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
    itemCat.put(0,"Functional");
    itemCat.put(1, "Interoperability");
    itemCat.put(2, "Load");
    itemCat.put(3, "Performance");
    itemCat.put(4, "Disponibility");
    itemCat.put(5, "Security");
    itemCat.put(6, "Usability");
    itemCat.put(7, "Other");

 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{projectRequirementManagementMB.selectedCat}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" >  
                                       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
                                <f:selectItems value=" {projectRequirementManagementMB.hereShouldbeCategoryValues}" />  
                                     </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Any idea will be apprecited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<f:selectItems>` already supports the `Map` interface:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{projectRequirementManagementMB.itemCat}" />
```

with just

```
public Map<Integer, String> getItemCat() {
   return itemCat;
}
```

However, the map keys are interpreted as item labels while the map values are interpreted as item values. If you can't swap the map keys/values in the model, then you need to swap them in the view in `<f:selectItems>` as follows, provided that your environment supports EL 2.2 (your question history confirms this).

```
<f:selectItems value="#{projectRequirementManagementMB.itemCat.entrySet()}" 
     var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Our `h:selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, a [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is a rather legacy data structure (from Java 1.0, 1996!!), you should be using its successor [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead. However, this has in turn like as the `Hashtable` another problem: the items by nature not ordered at all. You'd like to use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you'd like to maintain insertion order, or [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) if you'd like to have automatic sorting on keys.

```
itemCat = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
```